# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar los dobles espacios en blanco en python?

Tags: python, string

Necesito borrar los espacios en blanco que hay entre las palabras.

**Ejemplo:**

```
"Here'is'''some'''text'''I'''''wrote'''"
```

Lo siguiente es lo que intenté hacer, pero mis profesores no me dejan usar import re:

**Esto no funciona:**

```
s = "The fox    jumped    over    the   log."
i = s.split(" ")
k = " ".join(i)
print(k)
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a borrar esos dobles espacios en blanco?

Comment: Necesito eliminar los doble espacios en blanco. Pero no puedo importar re ya que mis profesores no me dejan. Hay alguna forma de poder hacerlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando la función split con un separador definido, que en este caso es un solo espacio. Llama la función sin parámetros:

```
ns = " ".join( s.split() )
print(ns)
'The fox jumped over the log.'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ponco!! Me salvaste. Ahora ya puedo separar palabra por palabra sin excepciones. Me salvaste el examen :)